# React - rendering to DOM on client side using local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing part of a React page where I want the text to change depending on a variable that I'm saving in local storage. Here are some snippets of the code:

Markets.jsx:

```
_getSelection: function ({ name, odds, url }, index) {
    return (
        <li key={ index }>
            <TouchableLink className="button" href={ url } effectOnClick>
                <span>{ name }</span>&ensp;<span>{ this._getOdds(odds) }</span>
            </TouchableLink>
        </li>
    );
},

_getOdds: function (odds) {
    var oddsFormat = this.betStore.getOddsFormat();

    return odds && odds[oddsFormat];
},
```

betStore.js:

```
getOddsFormat() {
    return this._localStorageService.getItem('oddsFormat') || 'fractional';
}
```

When initially rendering on the server, _getOdds always returns 'fractional' as there is no local storage there. On the client however it can return something else e.g. 'decimal' but the DOM isn't being updated to reflect this. Why is this? If I do a forceUpdate after the DOM has finished rendering it does update as expected.

Comment: Try to put the _getOdds inside componentDidMount, and put the _localStorageService.getItem('oddsFormat') inside the local state. And read from the local state instead of directly from the return of the function _getOdds.

Comment: I thought about doing that but it would have been slightly tricky as it's possible for a number of list items to be rendered all with their own odds. In the end I saved the oddsFormat in the state and set it in componentDidMount like you said.